# Looping over HTML Form elements in order to get Select type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="crewLeader" class="select">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I have inputs and selects in which it seems that the select boxes with this code that I am using is not grabbing the select box , I suppose since it is not of type input

```
var cbResults = "Issues Checked \n \n";
var textareas = "";
var selectbox = "";

for (var i = 0; i < form1.elements.length; i++) {
    var e = form1.elements[i];
    //console.log(e.name + "=" + e.value);

    if (form1.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        if (form1.elements[i].checked == true) {
            cbResults += form1.elements[i].value + ' \n';
          //console.log('cb=' + cbResults);
        }
    } else if (form1.elements[i].type == 'textarea') {
        textareas += form1.elements[i].name + " = " + form1.elements[i].value + ' \n';
    } else if (form1.elements[i].type == 'select') {
        //selectbox += form1.elements[i].value + ' \n';
        console.log('select');
        selectbox += form1.options[e.selectedIndex].text + ' / ' + form1.options[e.selectedIndex].value + ' \n';
    }


}
```

How to I loop over getting all the select boxes names and selected value for each ?

this does not work

```
 form1.elements[i].type == 'select')
```

**Update**

This part "works to enter this if :

```
   else if(form1.elements[i].tagName === 'SELECT')
```

However this code throws an error:

```
 selectbox += form1.options[e.selectedIndex].text + ' / ' + form1.options[e.selectedIndex].value + ' \n';
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: `form1.elements[i].tagName === 'SELECT' ` - if you want to do it in the same loop as the other element types.

Comment: Try to use tagName for select. form1.elements[i].tagName == 'select'

Comment: How do I only get all the selected option in each of the tagName == 'select'?

Comment: I added an update,  thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3Schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_type.asp),

> For a drop-down list this will be "select-one" or "select-multiple".

So, talking about single-choice select, you need to change your condition to:

```
form1.elements[i].type == 'select-one'
```

P.S. It is a good idea to replace `if`s chain to `switch`:

```
switch (form1.elements[i].type) 
{
    case 'select-one':
        break;
    case 'checkbox':
        break;
    case 'textarea': 
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Unknown type: " + form1.elements[i].type);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to use that with the code that I have.   I did add an update section to my code,  thoughts?